# Can we store temporary VALUES using Relational algebra

Tags: database, relation, relational-algebra

In relational algebra we can rename a table and have it as a temporary variable.
For example:

```
ρ(temp, Employees JOIN Works_In)
```

Now temp will be a table with the result of Employees being Joined with Works_In table.

Can we store temporary VALUES similar to the above example?
Say I got the oldest age of employees:

```
αMAX(age)Employees
```

Could I store that in a temp value so that I can reference it later and use it?
Will something like this work?

```
ρ(tempValue,  αMAX(age)Employees)
```

Comment: are you talking about a specific dialect of SQL?

Comment: Relational algebra @shafeen